# Data Validation without Drop Down List

Tags: excel, dropdown

I'm wondering if it is at all possible to use Data Validation in Microsoft Excel (2007) without creating a Drop Down list.

I'm currently creating a seating plan for work. I want the user to have the ability to freely type in the name in a cell (Desk). There are 7 teams of approximately 10-12 people. so finding a name in a long list would take up too much time. however the name typed in the cell has to be be an exact match from a list stored else where in the spreadsheet. The reason for this is i use a formula to show if everyone has been seated or not.

if a name is typed in and its not an exact i would like for an error message to pop up.

Any ideas if this is even possible?

im open to VBA. but a complete noob when it comes to VBA.

Thanks in advance.
Tom

Comment: My apologies... still new to this. i don't want every desk/cell to have a drop down list. i have 7 team of 10-15 people. so having to search through all the names through the drop down i feel is an unnecessary task when it can be freely typed. I want it so that if a name is typed in a desk/cell which isn't an exact match then it would bring up an error message.

Comment: A basic trick would be to use conditional formatting

Answer (score 1):

To get DV without the drop-down, use the *Custom > Formula* option.  Here is an example:

[image]

Only the set defined by the formula will be accepted and no drop-down will appear when the cell is clicked.

Comment: I think this is a really nice solution

Comment: there are over 100 names and over 50 desks, would it work with a formula with the range (AA1:AA128) instead of typing each name separately like your example?

Comment: @TomasJoeGemine  If the names are already stored in worksheet cells, then we can use a *MATCH()* formula,